# Tomcat 7's JspServlet not failing to compile JSPs with missing taglib imports

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

Various JSP pages were accidentally not importing taglibs they were using.
For example, the JSP was using: `<c:if>...</c:if>`
But, did not have `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>`.

When the JSPs were compiled by Tomcat 7, there were no errors.
The compiled JSP just contained `<c:if>` rather than replacing those tags.

Does anyone know how I can prevent the JSP from compiling successfully in these cases?

I used the following JspServlet configuration in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>mappedfile</param-name>
       <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>genStringAsCharArray</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to do this - the `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>` declaration tells tomcat's JSPC what to do when it comes across a `<c:.../>` tag. And if this declaration is missing, tomcat doesn't know what to do with it - so it doesn't touch it.

If you rely on this check, you might want to use some scripted checks in your build process, or use JSPC to precompile your JSPs during build time and check the resulting servlets for occurrences of suspect text/tags.

The number of possible tag libraries is unlimited, as are their names. And you might have more processing on the page than just the JSP-to-servlet compiter. I never came across an option to trigger an error when there is a namespaced HTML tag left - and for the reasons given in this answer I've never assumed there would be one.

Comment: Ok, that's helpful.  Thank you!